# Este archivo .WSDL funciona?

Tags: xml, webservice, soap, wsdl

Un cliente me ha enviado un archivo `.WSDL` para la creación de un servicio web, lo he validado usando el software altanova `SPY` y parece que és un fichero valido.

No obstante, cuando le envió datos a la función `CreateVoucher` mi programa no recibe nada (solo el `machineHandle`).

Este archivo `.WSDL` ha sido creado juntando diferentes .xsd con el software altanova `SPY`.

Aunque este validado, puede ser lo que haya juntado mal y no este funcionando correctamente? Yo no entiendo de `XML` por lo que no puedo decir si és problema del fichero `.WSDL` o del servicio web que estoy creando (no quiero molestar al cliente).

Si algún entendido de `XML` puede confirmarme que este archivo funciona correctamente se lo agradecería mucho.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/Imports">
            <xsd:import namespace="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:complexType name="MachineInfo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProjectId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SerialNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="MachineInfo" nillable="true" type="tns:MachineInfo"/>
            <xs:complexType name="DataFault">
                <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
                    <xs:extension base="tns:Fault">
                        <xs:sequence/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="DataFault" nillable="true" type="tns:DataFault"/>
            <xs:complexType name="Fault">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Code" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="Fault" nillable="true" type="tns:Fault"/>
            <xs:complexType name="ProcessingFault">
                <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
                    <xs:extension base="tns:Fault">
                        <xs:sequence/>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="ProcessingFault" nillable="true" type="tns:ProcessingFault"/>
            <xs:complexType name="VoucherData">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Address" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ArticleNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Currency" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Email" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MessageId" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PhoneNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Price" type="xs:decimal"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="VoucherData" nillable="true" type="tns:VoucherData"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
            <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
            <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
            <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
            <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
            <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
            <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
            <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
            <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
            <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="char">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="duration">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
                    <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
                    <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
            <xs:simpleType name="guid">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
            <xs:element name="RegisterMachine">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="vendingMachine" nillable="true" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher" type="q1:MachineInfo"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="RegisterMachineResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RegisterMachineResult" type="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="CreateVoucher">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="machineHandle" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="voucherData" nillable="true" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher" type="q2:VoucherData"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="CreateVoucherResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CreateVoucherResult" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="UploadPicture">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="machineHandle" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="voucherId" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="backgound" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="image" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="UploadPictureResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Ping">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PingResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_RegisterMachine_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegisterMachine"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_RegisterMachine_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegisterMachineResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_RegisterMachine_DataFaultFault_FaultMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="detail" element="q1:DataFault" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_RegisterMachine_ProcessingFaultFault_FaultMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="detail" element="q2:ProcessingFault" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_CreateVoucher_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateVoucher"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_CreateVoucher_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateVoucherResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_CreateVoucher_DataFaultFault_FaultMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="detail" element="q3:DataFault" xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_CreateVoucher_ProcessingFaultFault_FaultMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="detail" element="q4:ProcessingFault" xmlns:q4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_UploadPicture_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UploadPicture"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_UploadPicture_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:UploadPictureResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_UploadPicture_DataFaultFault_FaultMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="detail" element="q5:DataFault" xmlns:q5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_UploadPicture_ProcessingFaultFault_FaultMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="detail" element="q6:ProcessingFault" xmlns:q6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_Ping_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Ping"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IVoucher_Ping_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:PingResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IVoucher">
        <wsdl:operation name="RegisterMachine">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:IVoucher_RegisterMachine_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/RegisterMachine"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:IVoucher_RegisterMachine_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/RegisterMachineResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataFaultFault" message="tns:IVoucher_RegisterMachine_DataFaultFault_FaultMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/RegisterMachineDataFaultFault"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault" message="tns:IVoucher_RegisterMachine_ProcessingFaultFault_FaultMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/RegisterMachineProcessingFaultFault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateVoucher">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:IVoucher_CreateVoucher_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/CreateVoucher"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:IVoucher_CreateVoucher_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/CreateVoucherResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataFaultFault" message="tns:IVoucher_CreateVoucher_DataFaultFault_FaultMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/CreateVoucherDataFaultFault"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault" message="tns:IVoucher_CreateVoucher_ProcessingFaultFault_FaultMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/CreateVoucherProcessingFaultFault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="UploadPicture">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:IVoucher_UploadPicture_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/UploadPicture"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:IVoucher_UploadPicture_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/UploadPictureResponse"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataFaultFault" message="tns:IVoucher_UploadPicture_DataFaultFault_FaultMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/UploadPictureDataFaultFault"/>
            <wsdl:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault" message="tns:IVoucher_UploadPicture_ProcessingFaultFault_FaultMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/UploadPictureProcessingFaultFault"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Ping">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:IVoucher_Ping_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/Ping"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:IVoucher_Ping_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/PingResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="DefaultBinding_IVoucher" type="tns:IVoucher">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="RegisterMachine">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/RegisterMachine" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataFaultFault">
                <soap:fault name="DataFaultFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault">
                <soap:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="CreateVoucher">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/CreateVoucher" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataFaultFault">
                <soap:fault name="DataFaultFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault">
                <soap:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="UploadPicture">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/UploadPicture" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="DataFaultFault">
                <soap:fault name="DataFaultFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault">
                <soap:fault name="ProcessingFaultFault" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Ping">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher/IVoucher/Ping" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Pongo el XML que estoy enviando, falla la parte de voucherData, no recibo ningún elemento de dentro.

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:vouc="http://xml.hugwi.ch/2018/07/spider/voucher" xmlns:hug="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hugwi.SpiderCloud.Voucher">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <vouc:CreateVoucher>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <vouc:machineHandle>2</vouc:machineHandle>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <vouc:voucherData>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hug:Address>as</hug:Address>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hug:ArticleNumber>12</hug:ArticleNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hug:Currency>12</hug:Currency>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hug:Email>12</hug:Email>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hug:MessageId>12</hug:MessageId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hug:PhoneNumber>?12</hug:PhoneNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <hug:Price>12</hug:Price>
         </vouc:voucherData>
      </vouc:CreateVoucher>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Según un validador xml, está todo bien a nivel de etiquetas. Podrías añadir un ejemplo de lo que estás enviando?

Comment: pon también el xml que envías al servicio para cotejar

Comment: Edito con el XML que estoy enviando.